# How do i calculate biggest case with a faster machine?

Tags: performance, processing-efficiency

The question is :

For a program requiring exactly n^2 "instructions" to handle an input case of size n and a machine on which the biggest input case that can be handled in an hour of computing time is 100, how big is the biggest case that can be handled in an hour if the machine is replaced with one 4 times faster?

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

**by enumeration**

case n requires n^2 instructions and computes in time t

**old machine**

case 100 requires 10,000 instructions and computes in 1 hour, rate = 10,000 instructions/hour

**new machine**

case 100 requires 10,000 instructions and computes in 15 min, rate = 40,000 instructions/hour

**therefore**

case unknown requires 40,000 instructions and computes in 1 hour

but because case n --> instructions = n^2 so unk = sqrt(40,000)

you do the rest, so you actually learn something on this homework problem!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I have learned it now, thank you!